# javascript node module.exports / require() code on the front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, browserify

I've been looking into using a library such as [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo) to be able to clean user submitted SVG code on the front end. SVGO is a node.js based library which typically works on the back end, so I've been trying to wrap my head around how to go about sending SVG code from the front end to the back end and then have the cleaned code regurgitated on the front end.

It's when I was trying to figure this out that I checked their [web app example](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/), which—upon inspection, runs code inside linked scripts that I would typically see on the back end on the front end. In particular, many of their functions have the signature ([full script](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/js/page.js)):

```
1: [function(require, module, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var loadScripts = require("./load-scripts"),
    ...
module.exports = exportedFunction;
}]
```

Pretty confusing, as this is typically JS that I've associated with the backend, particularly the `require`, `module.exports` syntaxes to name a few.

Question

1. Is this simply their entire library, SVGO, on the front end? Did they manually rewrite it to be compatible with the front end? Or is that what tools like browserfy are for?
2. If so, what are the benefits of running it on the front end vs on the back end? Would one be easier/are there some common guidelines on which to use where?
3. From initial glance, it seems that it would be easier to just run the SVGO library in browser and do my conversion there (as I wouldn't have to make a call to the back end). What is the general practice there?

Thanks for any insight. I'm trying to make sure I build my project in the way that makes most sense/up to web standards.

Comment: please take a look at [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org/). They both are module loaders for front-end.

Comment: @dandavis however, regarding the way the question is asked it doesn't mean he knows the library but "how would i browserify my backend code ?" ...

Comment: 1. browserify turns node.js packages into browser-runnable code, even if the output is ugly. 2. the client is free and safe, node.js can be expensive and risky. 3. the more cleanup you can do up-front, the more stuff your backend has time/ram to do.

Comment: @JuniusRendel: touchè

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answers:

1. They are using module loaders like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org/) to allow the use of commonjs modules in the browser. It doesn't mean all the library would work on the client side, using node io modules would not work for example.
2. It can be useful to make some cleanup on the browser side before sending (saving a few kBytes). Browser has the advantage to be free, you don't pay for hosting the code that run on the client side, some *optionnal* sanitization can be run on the browser. **But**: see 3.
3. Even if it is easy to make client-side sanitization, you should always check and sanitize user's inputs on the backend, especially `.svg` files as they can contain `<script>` tags that might allow XSS .

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. Under what situations then, is it preferable to have SVGO on the backend? If it is so beneficial to be ran as a front-end module, why was it written for the back end (other than those who are just intending on running it locally for their own use)?

Comment: It is not "so benefical" to run it on the frontend, it just CAN be run on the frontend, and CAN be benefical. Every hosting providers do not provide Nodejs hosting, maybe your sysadmin wouldn't be so enthusiastic about hosting an exposed nodejs server if he doesn't master this technology,etc... if you are uploading svg and **want to be sure** that your SVGs are optimized (on the frontend they won't if the user has disabled js, for example). However I don't know this library so I can't tell you more about it...

Comment: i don't think you should sanitize on the front, but you can do cleanup like cropping/resizing images, formatting phone numbers, and other cosmetic procedures that don't attempt to curtail risk.